# Clearance gem not always rendering the correct layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, controller, clearance

I am currently using the Clearance gem by thoughtbot have noticed when trying to get the different controllers to render a different layout that not always does it render the correct layout, it reverts back to my standard layout. I am currently setting the layouts via an initializer

```
Clearance::SessionsController.layout 'landing'
  Clearance::UsersController.layout 'landing'
```